# Sandbox on a Ubuntu server

Tags: security, ubuntu, sandbox, apparmor

I am totally new to server security and I am working on a project that makes me think that I need to take that seriously from the beginning to avoid problems.

I am creating an app for students to run python/perl codes from a web browser. Basically they will write their source code on the front end, when they submit a temporary file will be created on the server and a command will be executed ad then the file created will be destroyed after killing the process once finished.

Although it seems straightforward, I would like to be more secure about it. I would like to put all submitted codes to a container that it will be difficult to escape from, and with reduced privileges not accessing the system.

I was reading about a lot of things like Sandoxes, Jail, AppArmor etc but for a newbie it is hard to get through all this especially with a documentation that is not familiar.

Is there any clear documentation on how to sandbox user's codes/ scripts,  a kind of step by step tutorial to follow

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think LXC will be ideal for your use case. Check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LXC

It is a very light weight virtualization container.

Good folks @ Digital Ocean have written a tutorial on how to use it- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/getting-started-with-lxc-on-an-ubuntu-13-04-vps

Comment: So basically once we create a container we put the code inside we run it and then we destroy it if I understand well

Comment: @Dar - yes, that's pretty much it.

Comment: and what about dependencies, let's say I installed a specific python library on my server, will the script inside the container be able to access the library ?

Comment: No, it won't - what you can do is host your shared files on a read only CIFS share and mount this share in guest LXC container.

Comment: The only problem is that when a student submit a code from the browser, the controller ( I am using an MVC) will have a method that will call "sudo lxc-start -n my-container", I am just wondering how is that possible if the server ask for the root password, if I change the /etc/suodoers to www-data ALL=NOPASSWD it will probably work but it will not be safe

Comment: Your controller should be staring the container, not student's submitted code. In fact, at no point of time, student's submitted code should be allowed to run on host, your host should transfer the code to guest LXC container and run it there.